# RSelenium API broken today?

Tags: r, rselenium

This code has traditionally always worked for me to start RSelenium:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",port = 4444L)
```

But today I'm getting the following error message:

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") :    Timeout was reached:
> [api.github.com] Connection timed out after 10003 milliseconds

I've tried changing the port and using chrome instead of Firefox, but no dice. I'm wondering if the API is broken, or if something has gone wrong on my end? As far as I know, I haven't changed anything with my connection or machine since this code last worked yesterday. I admit I'm unsure how to troubleshoot this. (I don't use a proxy, and I am able to do GET requests no problem.)

Comment: That doesn't look like an issue with RSelenium but maybe with Github's API—whatever is being downloaded from there. It does seem like they're having some issues right now: https://downdetector.com/status/github/

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help!